# Select horses with logical operators

Tags: mysql, sql

I dont know where i am messing up at but im currently learning SQL and this has been frustrating me a bit.

The Horse table has the following columns:

```
ID - integer, primary key
RegisteredName - variable-length string
Breed - variable-length string
Height - decimal number
BirthDate - date
```

Write a SELECT statement to select the registered name, height, and birth date for only horses that have a height between 15.0 and 16.0 (inclusive) or have a birth date on or after January 1, 2020.

This is what ive written

```
SELECT *
FROM Horse
WHERE (Height >= '15.0' AND <= '16.0') 
   OR BirthDate >= '2020-01-01';
```

This is the Error It Keeps Giving me
Query failed: ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '<= '16.0')
OR BirthDate >= '2020-01-01'' at line 3

Comment: Typo: `WHERE Height >= 15.0 AND Height <= 16.0`, or better yet: `WHERE Height BETWEEN 15 AND 16`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try this

```
SELECT *
FROM Horse
WHERE (Height >= '15.0' AND Height <= '16.0') 
   OR BirthDate >= '2020-01-01';
```